# ANDROID - How can I center horizontally multiple Buttons in RelativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, togglebutton

ANDROID - Can we center horizontally multiple Buttons in RelativeLayout?

Q. how to remove this blank space and add all 4 buttons in center in relative layout, like we use in linear layout weights to divide equally all btns in horizontal space.

> I want to make all 4 buttons in center without any container.

[PLEASE! See this Problem IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOy1Q.png)

> CODE

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub_main_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggle1"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/program_outline"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/phase1_toggle_button"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggle2"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/program_outline"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toggle1"
                android:background="@drawable/phase2_toggle_button"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggle3"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/program_outline"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/toggle4"
                android:background="@drawable/phase3_toggle_button"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />

<ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/toggle4"
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/program_outline"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/phase4_toggle_button"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textOff=""
                android:textOn=""
                android:textStyle="bold" />
```

> I want to make all 4 buttons in center without any container.
>
> @Abhishek Patel Updated image is Here
>   [image]

[image: My XML]

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this using only a RelativeLayout. RelativeLayout allows you to align children relative to each other and itself. In order to achieve your requirement RelativeLayout need to accept all your buttons as single component which it cannot. So you need to wrap your buttons inside another layout to achieve this

Comment: ok @Abhishek Patel answer is nearly enough close

Comment: then what is the my issue?

Comment: you must use LinearLayout inside RelativeLayout in order to solve your problem

Comment: i know and have used it before

Comment: but that's time i does not want to us LL, i want to use RL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sub_main_dashboard"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toggle1"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toggle2"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggle4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/toggle3"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn=""
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: what changes you had made?

Comment: Use `android:layout_toRightOf` in each `ToggleButton`

Comment: sir i am using the same but they are coming from lef to right side not starting from center as you had did

Comment: Remove android:layout_gravity="start" from first toggle

Comment: same nothing happening
i put your exact same code in my relative layout same problem comes

Comment: please see above image

Comment: if this answer is not fully suitable as per your requirement, please don't mark it as accepted because in future others will also follow this wrong answer.

Comment: @ Däñish Shärmà it is accepted answer because in my layout its working perfectly please show my image in question.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those button in a Layout for ex.LinearLayout and apply centerInParent="true"

for ex:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/sub_main_dashboard"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
android:centerInParent="true"
android:orientation="horizontal"
...>

<ToggleButton .. />
<ToggleButton .. />
<ToggleButton .. />
<ToggleButton .. />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```